# The JSON input is NOT valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specification). Unexpected token

Tags: json

This is a very simple JSON url [http://clickbankproads.com/xmlfeed/woocommerce/zip/json/test.txt ][1]

[1]: http://clickbankproads.com/xmlfeed/woocommerce/zip/json/test.txt but fails to validate with the tool http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Any help would be appreciated. If I copy the contents the file directly to validator instead of specifying as url, it validates.

Here is the JSON content

> [
>   {
>   "count":"9431",
>   "batches":"38"
>   }
>   ]

Comment: change the name of the file to `test.json` and check

Comment: Tried but no use http://clickbankproads.com/xmlfeed/woocommerce/zip/json/json.json

Comment: your json link is not working

Comment: I think you have a UTF-8 "BOM" in there.